# Sample Session-State Store Provider - Microsoft Example

Tags: c#, .net, session, session-state

I'm trying to implement a Session-State Provider using this sample from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589.aspx

But I can't compile it, because .NET throws this errors:

```
Error   1   
'Project.Session.OdbcSessionStateStore' does not implement inherited abstract member     'System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase.CreateNewStoreData(System.Web.HttpContext, int)'

Error   2   'Project.Session.OdbcSessionStateStore.CreateNewStoreData(System.Web.HttpContext, double)' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'Project.Session.OdbcSessionStateStore'

Error   3   'Project.Session.OdbcSessionStateStore.CreateNewStoreData(System.Web.HttpContext, double)': no suitable method found to override
```

Exact piece of code with CreateNewStoreData override:

```
    //
    // SessionStateProviderBase.CreateNewStoreData
    //

    public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(
      HttpContext context,
      double timeout)
    {
        return new SessionStateStoreData(new SessionStateItemCollection(),
          SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context),
          (int)timeout);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your MSDN link, class `OdbcSessionStateStore` is inheriting from `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` abstract class. [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) for more info

As you will have to override all abstract methods from an abstract class (except if the class that you create is also an abstract class), in this example you will need to override the abstract method `CreateNewStoreData`. [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.createnewstoredata.aspx) for more info

When overriding the method signatures should match. In the sample code from your MSDN link the signature is

```
public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(
      HttpContext context,
      double timeout)
```

where as in the actual case it should have been

```
public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(
    HttpContext context,
    int timeout
)
```

Note the difference `double timeout` instead of `int timeout`

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in the sample. You'll need to change the **SessionStateStoreData** method signature to use an int for the timeout parameter, because that's how [the method signature in the base class is defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.createnewstoredata%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  (This class overrides the base method, so the method signature must be the same.)

```
      public override SessionStateStoreData CreateNewStoreData(
          HttpContext context,
          int timeout)
```

This means you'll also have to ensure the parameter passed to this method is an int, not a double.  I believe the sample class only contains one call to it, in GetSessionStoreItem.  all you have to do is cast the value to an int, like this:

```
      if (actionFlags == SessionStateActions.InitializeItem)
          item = CreateNewStoreData(context, (int) pConfig.Timeout.TotalMinutes);
      else
          item = Deserialize(context, serializedItems, timeout);
```